# Show that any norm is continuous w.r.t the 1-norm

Tags: continuity, normed-spaces, epsilon-delta

Let $f(x)$ denote any vector norm. Show that $f(x)$ is continuous with respect to the $1$-norm.

I'm using the $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ approach:

$f(x)$ is continuous at $x_0$ if, given any $\varepsilon>0 $ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that if

$$\|x-x_0\|_1 < \delta \Rightarrow |f(x)-f(x_0)|< \varepsilon$$

Is that what is meant by "with respect to the $1$-norm?" If it is, then my second question is how is this evaluated? I have tried with the triangle inequality and the similarity of norms but can't get anywhere. Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Presumably this is for finite dimensions.

Comment: Replace the norm on $f$ by absolute value.

Comment: @copper.hat yes for finite. Just replace it? If so what is the point on mentioning "w.r.t 1-norm? "

Comment: $f$ has values in $[0,\infty)$, the norm $\|\cdot \|_1$ is meaningless in that context.

Comment: The one norm applies to the domain here, implicitly the absolute value $|\cdot|$ is used on the range.

Comment: Ok that i understand now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big hint:
 $f(x) \le \sum_k |[x]_k| f(e_k)$.

Another hint:
$|f(x)-f(y)| \le f(x-y)$.

Combining:
$|f(x)-f(y)| \le f(x-y) \le \sum_k |[x]_k-[y]_k| f(e_k) \le M \sum_k |[x]_k-[y]_k| = M \|x-y\|_1$,
where $M= \max_k f(e_k)$.

Choose $\delta = {1 \over M} \epsilon$.

Comment: What does the $e_k $ stand for?

Comment: The $k$th unit vector.

Comment: Dont get anywhere...